# Watson speech to text with "interim_results = True" in python gives ValueError

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

When using the Watson Speech-to-Text service with Python SDK, setting `interim_results = True` gives me the following error every time:

```
File "c:\...\Miniconda2\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 16 column 2 - line 401 column 2 (char 256 - 8843)
```

I am running it with a .wav file that is about 6 seconds long (directory omitted):

```
with open("C:/Users/.../assistant_output.wav",
          'rb') as audio_file:
    transcript = speech_to_text.recognize(
        audio_file, content_type='audio/wav', interim_results = True)
```

When setting `interim_results = False` it works fine, but I would like to process with interim results.

Any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the API documentation `interim_results` is only applicable when using sessions or websockets.

> Recognize audio Sends audio and returns transcription results for a
>   sessionless recognition request. Returns only the final transcription
>   results; to enable interim results, use Sessions or WebSockets.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#recognize_audio_websockets